# Getting 'undefined reference to' using mingw32, but no linker error using mingw64, why?

Tags: linker, mingw, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile the examples for the LeapMotion API by using mingw on cygwin

When I compile with mingw64, it works fine:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -s -I ../include -L ../lib/x64/ ExampleConnection.cpp -lLeapC PollingSample.cpp -oPollingSample
```

but if I switch to 32 bit:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -s -I ../include -L ../lib/x86/ ExampleConnection.cpp -lLeapC PollingSample.cpp -oPollingSample
```

I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `LeapCreateConnection'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `LeapOpenConnection'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `LeapCloseConnection'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `LeapDestroyConnection'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `LeapDestroyConnection'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to `LeapOpenDevice'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0x1d2): undefined reference to `LeapGetDeviceInfo'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `LeapGetDeviceInfo'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0x26d): undefined reference to `LeapCloseDevice'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg2UNs3.o:ExampleConnection.cpp:(.text+0x4ac): undefined reference to `LeapPollConnection'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to change the position of -lLeapC in the command string, and inverting the order of .cpp files, but I get always the same error.

Comment: Do you have the right 32-libraries (`libLeapC.a`/`libLeapC.dll.a`)?

Comment: in /lib/x86 there are only LeapC.lib and LeapC.dll, same filenames as in /lib/x64

Comment: .lib usually means MSVC. MinGW uses .a for static libraries and .dll.a for shared libraries (along with the .dll).

Comment: but the 64 bit version works fine, and filenames are the same

Comment: can you check which symbols the DLL file exports (e.g. using `pexports`)?

Comment: I have just found differences due to name mangling, e.g. LeapCloseConnection (64bit) and _LeapCloseConnection@4 (32bit), otherwise they export exactly the same symbols. Anyways, I solved the problem as explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by converting LeapC.lib to LeapC.a in /lib/x86/ (and removing LeapC.lib from the folder)

```
gendef LeapC.dll //this generates LeapC.def
i686-w64-mingw32-dlltool.exe --def LeapC.def --dllname LeapC.dll --output-lib LeapC.a
```

Comment: Note you cannot generally link C++ code generated by two compilers. If it works, you're just lucky that you don't use this or that language feature or haven't run into a problem. The fact that the linker finds its symbols does not mean ABI, exception handling, and even standard library types or even the allocator are the same in the two parts of the code.